# ABC.js score: changing clef for a few measures

Tags: discussion, abcjs

I decided to try and use the ABC.js plugin to add a score excerpt to [this answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/85605/learning-the-concept-of-serialism-from-its-basics-where-should-i-start-from/85638#85638).

*(I had been wondering why ABC isn't used more often on this site, and now I know; it isn't the most user-friendly thing, and not being able to see the result before you post the answer is a serious drawback. There are sites where you can enter ABC and immediately see the results, so adding that to the editor would make it more useful.)*

Anyway, I have a practical question: is it possible to change clefs halfway through a score? Measures 7, 8 and the first note of measure 9 in the cello part are supposed to be written in a transposed alto clef. Beside the practical implications of staying in the bass clef, I'd prefer to quote the score as it was written.

Comment: I think abc questions are also fine on the main site, with extra visibility and rep-earning votes. FWIW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command which controls the clef is `K:` which also sets the key (it is unclear to me whether you need to specify the key here, but by using 'C' at least no extra accidentals will be printed).

And apparently (some) commands can be inserted by enclosing in `[ ]`.

So the following appears to work, using embedded `[K:]` commands.

```
    X:1
    L:1/8
    M:4/4
    K:C
    %%score V1 V2 VA CL
    V:V1 clef=treble name="Vn.I"
    V:V2 clef=treble name="Vn.II"
    V:VA clef=alto   name="Viola"
    V:CL clef=bass   name="Cello"
    % 1
    [V:V1] "P0""_0"=D4 "_1"^C4 | "_2"=A,A,A,"_3"_B, "_4"=F2 "_5"_E2  | "_6"=EEE"_7"=c "_8"_B4   | ("_9"=G4G)"_10"^FF"_11"=B |(=B8 | B3) z "I5"z4 | "_0"=gz/2g/2 g z z2 "_1"_a z | "_4"=e z z2 z2 "_6"=fz/2f/2 | f z z2 z4 |
    [V:V2] z2 "_3"_B, z "_8"_A, z "_10"^F z | z2 "_6"=E z "_11"=B, z "_1"^C z | z2 "_9"=G z "_0"=D z "_5"_E z | z4 "_1"^C2 C2 |^C2 "_5"^D2 (D4 | D) z "_6"=E z z "_0"=G"_1"_A"_2"=c | ("_3"=B4 B)("_4"=e"_5"^F2) | z "_6"=F"_7"=A"_8"^c ("_9"=D"_10"_e') (e'2 | (e'2) "_11"_B6) |
    [V:VA] z2 "_5"^D, z "_6"=E, z "_9"=G, z | z2 "_7"=C, z "_10"^F, z "_2"=A, z | z2 "_11"=B, z "_2"=A, z "_4"=F, z | z4 "_0"=D,2 D,2 |=D,2 "_4"=F,2 (F,4 | F,) z "_8"_A, z z4 | "_2"=C,z/2C,/2 C, z z2 =c z | "_3"=B z z2 z2 "_8"^C,z/2C,/2 | C, z z2 "_9"=Cz/2C/2 C z |
    [V:CL] z2 "_4"=F,, z "_7"=C, z "_11"=B,, z |\
    z2 "_8"_A,, z "_9"=G,, z "_0"=D,, z |\
    z2 "_10"^F, z "_1"^C, z "_3"_B,, z |\
    z4 "_2"=A,,2 A,,2 |\
    =A,,2 "_3"_B,,2 (B,,4 |\
    B,,) z "_7"=C, z z4 |\
    [K:C alto] "_1"_Az/2A/2 A z z2 "_0"=G, z |\
    "_5"^F z z2 z2 "_7"=Az/2A/2 |\
    A [K:C bass] z z2 "_10"_E,,z/2E,,/2 E,, z |
```

```
X:1
L:1/8
M:4/4
K:C
%%score V1 V2 VA CL
V:V1 clef=treble name="Vn.I"
V:V2 clef=treble name="Vn.II"
V:VA clef=alto   name="Viola"
V:CL clef=bass   name="Cello"
% 1
[V:V1] "P0""_0"=D4 "_1"^C4 | "_2"=A,A,A,"_3"_B, "_4"=F2 "_5"_E2  | "_6"=EEE"_7"=c "_8"_B4   | ("_9"=G4G)"_10"^FF"_11"=B |(=B8 | B3) z "I5"z4 | "_0"=gz/2g/2 g z z2 "_1"_a z | "_4"=e z z2 z2 "_6"=fz/2f/2 | f z z2 z4 |
[V:V2] z2 "_3"_B, z "_8"_A, z "_10"^F z | z2 "_6"=E z "_11"=B, z "_1"^C z | z2 "_9"=G z "_0"=D z "_5"_E z | z4 "_1"^C2 C2 |^C2 "_5"^D2 (D4 | D) z "_6"=E z z "_0"=G"_1"_A"_2"=c | ("_3"=B4 B)("_4"=e"_5"^F2) | z "_6"=F"_7"=A"_8"^c ("_9"=D"_10"_e') (e'2 | (e'2) "_11"_B6) |
[V:VA] z2 "_5"^D, z "_6"=E, z "_9"=G, z | z2 "_7"=C, z "_10"^F, z "_2"=A, z | z2 "_11"=B, z "_2"=A, z "_4"=F, z | z4 "_0"=D,2 D,2 |=D,2 "_4"=F,2 (F,4 | F,) z "_8"_A, z z4 | "_2"=C,z/2C,/2 C, z z2 =c z | "_3"=B z z2 z2 "_8"^C,z/2C,/2 | C, z z2 "_9"=Cz/2C/2 C z |
[V:CL] z2 "_4"=F,, z "_7"=C, z "_11"=B,, z |\
z2 "_8"_A,, z "_9"=G,, z "_0"=D,, z |\
z2 "_10"^F, z "_1"^C, z "_3"_B,, z |\
z4 "_2"=A,,2 A,,2 |\
=A,,2 "_3"_B,,2 (B,,4 |\
B,,) z "_7"=C, z z4 |\
[K:C alto] "_1"_Az/2A/2 A z z2 "_0"=G, z |\
"_5"^F z z2 z2 "_7"=Az/2A/2 |\
A [K:C bass] z z2 "_10"_E,,z/2E,,/2 E,, z |
```

Comment: Hm, I can get it to work on other sites, but not on Music SE. Maybe we have an older version installed.

Comment: See Edit!!!!!!!

Comment: Great! Can you add a version of the code that isn't rendered? I can't press [edit] to look at how you did that for some reason.

Comment: No problem. Done!

Comment: Works like a charm :-) And by using `[K:C alto 4]` I can move the clef up to the fourth stave as it is done in the original score.

Comment: BTW, if you don't see an 'edit' link, but do see an 'edited .. ago' link, you can use that to see the various revisions, with links to source for each one.